# Me aparece el popup de error pero la función funciona

Tags: angular

estoy creando una función que agrega datos a una tabla, le estoy poniendo con suscribe que cuando de error aparezca un mensaje de error.
Pero la cuestión es que crea los datos en la tabla y me dice que no lo puede hacer.

```
    onCreate():void{
        const habi =new Habilidade(this.area, this.porcentaje);
        this.habilidadservice.save(habi).subscribe(
          data=>{alert("Habilidad creada"); location.reload();}, 
            err=>{alert("Fallo Creacion"); this.form.reset();});
      }
```

Estoy usando visual estudio y angular 15

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el contenido de `err`?

Comment: Te sale el mensaje de "Habilidad creada" tambien?